# Print page without modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page with a modal. One option in this modal is to print the page using `window.print()`.

This prints the modal and not the page.

How can I print just the page and not the modal?

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan Hi. It's not my fault my Google-fu is not on par with yours. This is of course going to get buried but there's no reason to leave condescending aggressive messages before you mark something as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set up a print stylesheet. If your modal content has an ID of `#modal`, then this will hide it when printed:

```
@media print {
    #modal{
        display: none;
    }
}
```